# Помогите понять смысл, изучаю теоретическую часть о типах данных

Tags: java

[image: Как это понять?]
[image: Как это понять?]

Не могу осмыслить имена переменных.

Какую роль здесь играют точки?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что в выделенной мной области есть 3 разные переменные никак не связанные между собой.

1. cat
2. cat.owner
3. cat.owner.name

и можно ли из назвать по другому, используя не точки а знак нижнего подчеркивания, например так:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat_owner = new Person();
cat_owner_name = "God";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас есть только одна переменная - `cat`. Эта переменная является *ссылкой* на объект класса `Cat`, созданный в куче. Используя оператор "точка" вы можете получать доступ к полям и методам объекта, на который ссылается ссылка, таким как `owner`, `territory` и т.п. Соответственно поле `owner` также является ссылкой, но на объект класса `Person` и используя оператор "точка" вы можете обращаться к полям и методам этого объекта, таким как `name` и `age`.

Если вместо точки использовать знак подчеркивания то вся конструкция будет одним идентификатором. т.е. `cat.owner.name` - это три имени, два оператора "точка" `cat_owner_name` - это одно длинное имя.

Comment: А скажите тогда зачем в строке cat.owner.name = "God"; обращаться к owner чтобы засунуть в name текст "God"?
можно же тогда написать cat.name = "God", причем тут owner?

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко owner - это владелец в переводе с английского, так что `cat.name` - это имя кошки, а `cat.owner.name` - это имя владельца кошки. Это два разных поля у двух разных объектов.

Answer (score 0):

1. Нет.
2. Нельзя.

Хотя 2. в принципе можно (с небольшими добавлениями), но это будет совсем не то же самое.

Точки означают своего рода иерархию -  `cat` имеет вложенный объект `owner`, который имеет переменную `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Есть объект кошка  - cat
У этой кошки есть свойство хозяин - person
У хозяина есть имя - name.

Через точку вы обращаетесь к свойству объекта

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю к рассуждениям коллег, важное замечание:

Точка - это специальный вид операции/нотации (не путать с оператором), по извлечению/доступу к членам класса. Это фактически соглашение, договоренность о том, что через точку пишется доступ к членам класса/объекта.

Если бы договоренность была не точка, а символ подчеркивания, то так оно и было бы. К счастью или к несчастью договорились, что в Java это символ точки `.`, а не `_`

```
Cat cat;
int color=cat.color;
```

В С/С++, например для ссылок используется символ `->`, для самих объектов `.`:

```
Cat *catReference;
Cat cat;

int color=catReference->color;
color=cat.color;
```

В SmallTalk, например, точка - является символом конца выражения, ну и т.д...

Comment: В С ссылок нет, а в С++ и для ссылок и для самих объектов используется только точка.

Comment: имеются ввиду указатели, конечно же :)